# Undefined reference to SSL_library_init and SSL_load_error_strings

Tags: c, openssl, undefined-reference

I am implementing a OpenSSL code and have already included required header files but still I am getting errors like *

> undefined reference to `SSL_library_init`

I guess it's a linking error rather than a compilation error.

I am implementing it in Linux box using slickeditor.

Comment: And how are you invoking the linker?  Are you instructing it to link against the OpenSSL library, such as with `-lcrypto` for gcc?

Comment: nope. the machine I got already has openssl. when I do which openssl it shows be path like /usr/bin/openssl. So the next step I did was to include header files in my existing code and then in slickeditor property i i tried to include -llibeay32 and -lssleay32. But no joy

Comment: The OpenSSL library is called libcrypto.  Link to it with with -lcrypto.  I don't know anything about SlickEdit.  Is it invoking the compiler and linker for you, is that done in a makefile, or do you do it on a command line?  Somehow you need to tell the linker to link to libcrypto.  For invoking gcc on the command line, this means adding the option `-lcrypto`.

Comment: New udpate. I did try to include -lssl in slickeditor  and still no joy

Comment: The slickeditor provides complier G++ and linker as well. I did try to add -lcrypto in it. Also I have noticed there is -lcrpt and not crypto there. Still no joy

Comment: Apologies, `SSL_library_init` is in libssl, so the link option would be `-lssl`.  `ldd $(which openssl)` will show you how your openssl is linked and where those libraries are.  If it still doesn't work, perhaps that directory is not on the path for the linker.  You can add that path with `-Lpath`, such as `-L/lib/`

Comment: I have copied both libraires from /usr/lib  into directory of project lib  and issued command -lssl and -lcrypto .. But still no joy

Comment: on typing command ld $(which openssl)  I got following o/p

Comment: ' 'linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00110000)
 libssl.so.7 => /lib/libssl.so.7 (0x00411000)
 libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00919000)
 libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00877000)
 libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x007ec000)

Comment: libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x004d2000)
 libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x007d5000)
 libcrypto.so.7 => /lib/libcrypto.so.7 (0x03d94000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x0038d000)

Comment: libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x003cd000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x001f7000)
 libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x004f9000)
 libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00872000)

Comment: So libssl is in /lib/.  Try the linker options `-L/lib/ -lssl` (in that order).

Comment: I cant able to issue via command prompt . But I will try to figure out how to use linker in slickeditor as I am also too new in slick editor

Comment: You should get a minimal test case working on the command line.  `#include "whatever" \n int main(void) { SSL_library_init(blah, blah, blah); return 0; }` and then `g++ my_minimal_test_case.c++ -lssl`.  If this works then you don't understand your editor/IDE.  If it doesn't then you have some configuration issue.

Comment: Yeah thats works . SO I guess there is prob with my editor. I will investigate in that. AND THANKS A LOT for help

Comment: Thats done. I have copied crypto.a and ssl.a into lib folder of project and added -lcrypto -lssl in make file and its done.

Answer (score 31):

Link against `libssl` and `libcrypto`. Your `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` would be as follows. Order matters for `LDLIBS`:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/ssl/lib
LDLIBS = -lssl -lcrypto
```

Don't worry about adding the "lib" in front of library name, or the "so" or "a" suffix. The linker will do it for you.

If you are building from the command line, then you would use the following. Again, order matters.

```
gcc foo.c -o foo.exe -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

If you are using the system's OpenSSL, then you can omit `-L/usr/local/ssl/lib`.

Comment: According to comments on the question, `SSL_library_init` is in libssl, so shouldn't the correct order be `LDLIBS = -lcrypto -lssl` instead?

Comment: @CraigScott - Sorry about the late reply. Order matters because its a single pass linker. When LD encounters unsatisfied link symbols, it notes them and looks for them in libraries that follow. If `libcrypto` was first, then `libssl` would have unsatisfied symbols like `BN_new` because `libcrypto` needs to follow `libssl` to satisfy the missing symbols. The other option is a two-pass linker. Sometimes you will also see something like `-la -lb -la` (`liba` followed by `libb` followed by `liba`). Its usually due to a circular reference lurking behind the scenes.

Comment: "Order matters" was the key for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

For me this meant to install

```
 apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Was trying to compile AOSP on Ubuntu 18, and had to downgrade openssl 1.1 -> 1.0.1 , but had installed libssl-dev

Comment: High five to both of you.  I had the same issue and the combination of these two comments made me realize it.

Answer (score 8):

These methods are deprecated in OpenSSL 1.1. You don't need to use it more. You can just remove it. More info in OpenSSL manual.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `-lssl -lcrypto` to your Makefile and it should work.

Example of Makefile:

```
foo: foo.o
g++ -std=c++17 -o foo foo.cpp -lcrypto -lssl
```

Answer (score 0):

ldd libssl.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found

sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1

libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f17d46c7000)